# whirlpool top load washer stops at rinse cycle, can open and then shut lid and then starts

Tags: repair

not always but most of the time my washer is stopping after the rinse cycle.  I can open the lid a little and then shut it and then it will start.  sometimes takes just one open and shut, other  times may take two or three times.  What is the problem?

Comment: How old is it? My wild guess would be a worn switch. But knowing Whirlpool's horrific quality, it can be anything. If there is a mainboard inside, sometimes just re-soldering all joints on it may fix the issue.

Comment: Not exactly sure. House was built around 2001. Probably was in the house new. I bought house about 4.5 years ago.

Comment: I figured probably the switch or the security lock but don't really have a clue.   Thought that opening the lid and shutting starts it going might be a giveaway for someone.

Comment: It looks like you made a new account. You should mod flag this question so a moderator can merge them for you. Then you can edit the question

Comment: @Machavity the best advice is give is to direct the OP at the "contact us" page where one of the options is to request an account merge. Moderators can't merge accounts, only employees can do that.

Comment: @Machavity Moderators can't merge accounts. Users have to do it themselves by selecting "contact us" at the bottom of the page, then "I need to merge user profiles" from the dropdown.

Comment: @ChrisF Learned something today

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Ajeh. Check the Lid Switch connections, including the ground right near the switch. I'd throw in a new Lid Switch and see if the problem continues or disappears. They're usually cheap and you may be able to shift the drum around enough to not take anything apart.

The only other culprit, I'm familiar with, would be the Control Knob...it directs everything. In some cases those can be very pricey, so you'll have to decide if it's money better spent on a single expensive part or a whole new washer.

Comment: I replace the lid switch on my Kenmore (which I think is really a Whirlpool) about every 4 or 5 years. I don't know why the switches wear out so fast, but they do.

Comment: It's amazing isn't it. They put out such crap anymore that it's less headache and even expense to just trash an entire appliance for what they charge for tiny individual parts. But yeah, GE (used to) own most every appliance out there and just charged a little more for each brand, without even changing the look, knobs, buttons or trims. Planned obsolescence has now become forced obsolescence...only buy the low-end stuff, they last much longer.